# How do I use PHP to execute a SQL file in batch that contains thousands of statements?

Tags: php, sql, xampp, mysqli-multi-query

I have a `.sql` file that contains a handful of `TRUNCATE`, `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE TABLE` statements as well as thousands of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

I'm trying to use PHP to execute all the statements in the file in batch as follows:

```
$sql = file_get_contents('path/to/sql/file.sql');
$link->($sql);
```

Where `$link` is a valid MySQLi DB link. I've also tried swapping out `$link->($sql)` with `$link->multi_query($sql)`, but neither seem to work.

If it makes any difference, I'm attempting to do this in an XAMPP localhost environment on Windows 10 with PHP 7.1 and MariaDB 15.1.

Does anyone know why this would cause problems and not work?
What's the best way in PHP to execute a SQL file with thousands of statements in it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the errors being displayed

Comment: I use this. It is just something I put together for me. It works. You can at least see how the commands work on windows. :) Yes, it is run as part of my unit tests. I use it to set up the database.  https://pastebin.com/wWjfsYCQ

Comment: I see, @RyanVincent. Basically, you have to use the `exec` function in PHP to run the `mysql` command with certain options. That makes sense. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to do this if MySQL and Apache/PHP are installed on separate servers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan, thanks again for the advice. As you suggested, running the mysql command directly on the SQL file is the way to go.

The following worked for me:

```
shell_exec('C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql.exe -h localhost -u root -ppassword -D db-name "SELECT * FROM table-name;"');
```

Please note that you don't want a space between the `-p` option and the password itself. If you don't have a password, then just remove the `-p` option altogether.

**Edit**: The sample command above is a very arbitrary one to demonstrate running the `mysql` command. If you want to read and execute a bunch of SQL statements in a file, the following is more what you need:

```
shell_exec('C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql.exe -h localhost -u root -ppassword -D db-name < C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\path\\to\\file.sql');
```